# Proof in textbook regarding the uncountability of the set of all functions from $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ to the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In her proof of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjkZY.png) problem, Epp [defines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2sx3.png) a function that I do not understand. How is it possible for a function that sends each positive integer $n$ to $a_n$ to have codomain $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$. My understanding of this function is that it would map $2$ to $0.02$. Could someone please explain to me what exactly this function does?

Comment: The function $F$ is defined for numbers in $[0,1]$.

Comment: $(F(0.a_1 a_2...) )(n) = a_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $x = 0.1358$, then $F(0.1358)(1) = 1$, $F(0.1358)(2) = 3$, $F(0.1358)(3) = 5$, $F(0.1358)(4) = 8$, and $F(0.1358)(n)$ for $n \geq 5$ is equal to zero.

The key thing to understand is that $F$ evaluated at a number in $[0,1]$ is itself a function.